# Internet not working after configuring server for DNS with dyndns

Tags: networking, dns, dynamic-dns

**Objective to be achieved**: To access the  server using a name `server.xyz.com`.

I've a domain xyz.com and a server behind a router. Also, I've configured my server with dyndns. On executing the following command

> dig xyz.com

I get this output:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.17.rc1.el6_4.4 <<>> xyz.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 5351
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;xyz.com.       IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
xyz.com.    1800    IN  SOA ns1.mydyndns.org. zone-admin.dyndns.com. 2013052111 10800 1800 604800 1800

;; Query time: 180 msec
;; SERVER: 208.76.58.198#53(208.76.58.198)
;; WHEN: Wed May 22 17:44:28 2013
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 106
```

However,

`ping google.com`

gives me

`ping: unknown host google.com`

Moreover,

`hostname`

displays

`server.xyz.com`

Futhermore,

`domainname`

displays

`xyz.com`

I've also configured my dlink router to update public ipaddress with dyndns, using Dynamic DNS configuration in the router.

Have I configured dns properly? Also, I'm not being able to access internet after the configuration.

Comment: Sounds like your outgoing DNS is incorrect if you can't resolve external websites.

Comment: Travis, I figured it out. I had not configured the nameservers with my domain registrar. Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

In my dyndns account, the delegation status showed **Incorrect**. This implied that I had not **configured the nameservers with my domain registrar**, the site from where I bought my domain.

On doing the needful, the delegation status changed to **Correct**. Please note, it did not require me to modify my `resolv.conf`